# iCloudKit space storage allotted storage quota management/monitoring

Tags: ios, storage, limit, monitoring, icloud

Trying to use/understand iCloudKit limitations since I want to try and build an app that lets users share its public database space to upload small photos (VGA resolution). How can I find out what the available public database left for my app is? What is it using today? Can I do so within the app itself? What happens when you exceed the allowed space? what happens when I exceed the upload/download limit that day?

Do I understand the documentation correctly that I think suggests the common space available to you increases with the number of users of said app, so 1 user gets 100mb of asset storage for my app and 10 users get 1gb [obviously split evenly among them) in the public database for my app?

Anybody?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you are right! but there is a limit too, since Apple iCloudKit allow you to have only 10 Millions user only! if you exceed the 10 Millions user you have to pay the extra fee which is already stated in the iCloud website. [image]

Let make it more detail:
- in iCloud each individual user get 5GB of storage for their app from apple such as Contact, Map, Mail, **Your app**(in this case, apple also not recommend dev to store too much data, coz user will feel uncomfortable since their iCloud is limited), and etc. 
- So what is 100 MB is for ? it is for you public asset storage of you app service which is can allow different user/app to access it!

**Cloudkit free storage and data transfer plan
For every Cloudkit container, you start out with:**

Storage – 5 GB for assets – 50 MB for database

Data Transfer – 25 MB/day for assets – 250 KB/day for database

*And for every user you get a bonus of:*

Storage – 100 MB for assets – 1 MB for database

Data Transfer – 0.5 MB/day for assets – 5 KB/day for database

**Sample calculations**
To get a better feel of the numbers, I’ve created a few sample calculations.

With 1K Cloudkit users you get

Storage – 105 GB for assets – 1 GB for database

Data Transfer – 505 MB/day for assets – 5.25 MB/day for database

More detail about iCloudKit go to http://blog.equanimity.nl/blog/2014/06/13/cloudkit-storage-and-data-transfers/
and 
http://appleinsider.com/articles/14/06/07/apples-new-icloud-storage-plans-cheap-for-consumers-even-cheaper-for-developers

More detail explanation about container of iCloudKit :
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Introduction_to_CloudKit_Data_Storage_on_iOS_8
the image bellow is from techotopia.com 
[image]
Hope this help.

Comment: Do you get that much free storage per app? Or is it a sum total of all of your apps?